# Google BigQuery Grouping by Contains Keyword

Tags: google-bigquery

Given an example dataset I'm trying to sort through:

```
email,domain_name
name1@email.com,superlorem.com
name2@email.com,superdolor.com
name3@email.com,superamet.com
name4@email.com,badlorem.com
name5@email.com,baddolor.com
name6@email.com,badamet.com
```

And I'm starting off with a query such as...
    SELECT email
    FROM table
    WHERE 
        (domain_name contains 'dolor') or
        (domain_name contains 'sit') or
        (domain_name contains 'amet')
    GROUP BY email

Is it possible to group results by the "contains" word, such as 'dolor', 'sit', and 'amet'? The words wouldn't exist by themselves in a column (Such as being part of a domain name, superlipsum.com for example). My end goal is to have a CSV that resembles this:

```
Dolor,column1
Dolor,column2
Dolor,column3
Sit,column4
Sit,column5
Sit,column6
Sit,column7    
Amet,column8
```

Comment: can you provide example of table data that will end up with your expected output

Comment: Oops, can't format a comment so I will edit the post

Comment: are email and domain_name those two (a and b) columns in your question? and what is "column" in this case?

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response and sorry for the delay! I was on a phone call and hadn't finished editing the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need separate table with all words (dolor, sit, amet, etc.) in it
Then, below should work

```
SELECT 
  word,
  email
FROM yourTable AS t1
CROSS JOIN wordsTable AS t2
WHERE domain_name CONTAINS word
ORDER BY word, email
```

If you have limited list of words  - you can use below (on-fly) version

```
SELECT 
  word,
  email
FROM yourTable AS t1
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT f0_ AS word FROM
  (SELECT 'dolor'),
  (SELECT 'sit'),
  (SELECT 'amet')
) AS t2
WHERE domain_name CONTAINS word
ORDER BY word, email
```

Both will produce something like below

```
word    email    
amet    name3@email.com  
amet    name6@email.com  
dolor   name2@email.com  
dolor   name5@email.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use regular expressions, i.e.

```
SELECT 
 regexp_extract(domain_name, r'(dolor|sit|amet)' word,
 email, 
FROM table
```

BigQuery will compile automata for regular expression once, and will efficiently apply it to all rows. I expect this to give better performance than JOIN.

Comment: just to note: the limitation with regexp_extract use is that you can only hard code values, so more generic case with quite a number of words will not work well or at all